# Nuget auth with API key in environment variable

Tags: nuget, cicd, nuget-package-restore

In my CI/CD pipeline I want to pull nuget packages from a custom registry. I must use an access token.

I defined the `ACCESS_TOKEN` environment variable in the pipeline. And my `nuget.config` has this:

```xml
<apikeys>
  <add key="https://example.com/api/index.json" value="%ACCESS_TOKEN%" />
</apikeys>
```

But I nonetheless get 401/Unauthorized.

The `%foo%` syntax is something I saw on the docs page. Can it be used for the API key?